# Unable to see the Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am loading a Dropdown inside a repeater but i am unable to see the repeater.Why i am unable to see it?

aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">    
    <ItemTemplate> 
       <table>
           <tr>
             <td>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">                     
                  <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem> <asp:ListItem>Left</asp:ListItem> 
                  <asp:ListItem>Right</asp:ListItem> 
                  <asp:ListItem>SubString</asp:ListItem>
               </asp:DropDownList> 
              <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

codebehind:

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Common.LoadExample();
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList6") ;
        ddl.DataSource = dt;
        ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
        ddl.DataValueField = "Name";
        ddl.DataBind();

}
```

// datatable for loading

```
   public static DataTable LoadExample()
    {
        DBAccess objDBAccess = new DBAccess();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            objDBAccess.AddParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            dt = objDBAccess.ExecuteDataTable("usp_test");
            return dt;
        }
        catch 
        {

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I am getting data into the datatable but i am unable to bind it to the DDL

Comment: Have you tried debugging this method? If a breakpoint doesn't get hit, you most likely have no data in your Repeater.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Why would that help? If the Repeater isn't displayed, why does it matter what the DataTable for the `ddl` is?

Comment: The breakpoint is not going inside of the repeater item data bound

Comment: @Curt I thought he is unable to see the ddl

Comment: Post your markukp. You need to point the repeater to your ItemDataBound handler in markup or add it in your Page_Init method.

Comment: Are you doing Repeater.DataBind(). Your question says you are unable o see the Repeater.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That means that you Repeater is not bound to ItemDataBound event correctly. Is the name of the repeater "Repeater1"? Also, check if you are actually locating the dropdownList in "DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList6") ;"

Comment: @RoyiNamir Even if theres no data in the `ddl` it'll still render as an empty `<select>` element. The issue must be with the Repeater data binding.

Comment: @Curt if he doesnt have any data (in datatable) - he wont see any DDL.

Comment: Can anyone provide me some code fo this?

Comment: @Newbie can you upload the markup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the reason is that you haven't checked for the [`ItemType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype.aspx), therefore you're getting an exception because the header doesn't contain the `DropDownList` but only the items:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
    // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course there are other reasons why a repeater is not visible.

- `Repeater` or one of it's container controls is `Visible="false"`
- it's `DataSource` is null or empty
- you have not databound it at all
- .... (without code it's difficult to help further)

**Edit** Please don't comment but edit your question with important informations.

> The breakpoint is not going inside of the repeater item data bound –
>   Newbie 25 mins ago

Then you have not `DataBind` it or the `DataSource` is null or empty. You should show us the code where you assign  the datasource and call databind.

Comment: his _Repeater1_ItemDataBound_ code is not in try catch so he should see the exception.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: He hasn't shown the _binding code_ at all(the code where he binds the repeater itself). So of course it's also possible that there are other reasons why it is not shown(`Visible=false` as a stupid example). But the missing check for the ItemType is for sure a reason for an exception when the DropDownList is not in the header).

Comment: Still the breakpoint is not working.

Comment: Tim , I corrected myself. his Repeater1_ItemDataBound .... his code  should raise an excption if he isnt checking the type - but he doesnt get an exception (IMHO)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `ItemDataBound` is an event which is triggered for every RepeaterItem. So it might be possible that he has a `try{ repeater.DataBind() } catch { }` or that there's another reason why he doesn't see the exception(global logging etc.).

Comment: @TimSchmelter you right , but without the code we cant tell. ( he can also have a ddl in each section of the repeater so it wont fail also....But thats why i asked him to uplaod the markup

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
            onitemdatabound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
       
       <ItemTemplate>
       <table>
       <tr>
       <td> <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Left</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Right</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>SubString</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server">
           </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: Why do you have that <table> <tr> and <td> elements in the itemtemplate? You do not seem to be closing them either.

Comment: @Newbie: Edited my answer. Please don't comment important informations(others want to see it too) and don't comment code at all(it's not readable). Use the edit function in your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have the dropdowns inside the repeater so what i have to bind to the repeater control??

Comment: A repeater's purpose is to repeat items n times.  Assuming that the repeater should repeat items for every user in a table called `TUser`, you would bind it to that table and then `DataBind` it. For every user it'll show these dropdowns then. If you have only one item use a FormView instead.

Comment: Yeah but i am not binding any labels inside the repeater so i am unable to display the control,and i am not binding any datasource to it coz i have DDL's in the repeater

Comment: @Newbie: You have still not understand that there's no relation between the repeater's datasource and the datasource of one (or multiple) of it's child controls. You use different datasources. You don't need to use a Label to show something, a DroPDownList is also a control which displays _something_.

Comment: But why the controls are repeating?? if i place a DDL i am getting it for 5 times can i avoid it?

Comment: You get the DropDownList for every repeater item. So either you use the wrong datasource or you should put the dropdownlist outside of the repeater (or use a FormView instead).

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example to give you idea of how things should be:

On ASPX page:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrTest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        ID: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>
        <br />
        Name: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%>
        <br />
        Select: <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlSelect" />
        <br /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

On Page_Init, if you do not have `"AutoEventWireUp = true"` on ASPX side, you would want to bind the ItemDataBound event for repeater:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    rptrTest.ItemDataBound +=
        new RepeaterItemEventHandler(rptrTest_ItemDataBound);
}
```

On Page_Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is an example, but you should get this data from database
    List<File> myObjects = new List<File>(new[]
    {
        new File { ID = 1, Name = "Foo", AListOfStrings = stringList },
        new File { ID = 2, Name = "Bar", AListOfStrings = stringList },
        new File { ID = 3, Name = "Baz", AListOfStrings = stringList },
        new File { ID = 4, Name = "Quux", AListOfStrings = stringList }
    });

    rptrTest.DataSource = myObjects;
    rptrTest.DataBind();
}
```

On ItemDatabound event of repeater:

```
void rptrTest_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
    {
        // Find the DropDownList in the repeater's ItemTemplate
        // so we can manipulate it.
        DropDownList ddlSelect =
            e.Item.FindControl("ddlSelect") as DropDownList;
        if (ddlSelect == null) return;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = Common.LoadExample();

        ddlSelect .DataSource = dt;
        ddlSelect .DataTextField = "Name";
        ddlSelect .DataValueField = "Name";
        ddlSelect .DataBind();
    }
}
```